# Dynamically switching template of a directive

Tags: angularjs

Is possible (I'm guessing it is) to dynamically change template of a directive, depending on certain factors?

So, I see how theoretically it's possible - you can put all different templates into the $templateCache beforehand, and retrieve the one you need during directive compilation

something like:

```
restrict:'E'
scope:
    data:'='
    template:'='
link:(scope, elem, attrs)->
    html = $templateCache.get(scope.template)
    tElement.html(html)
```

However real question is, would be the right thing to do so? Will that badly affects performance? If for example directive used as a cell in a big grid?

Answer (score 2):

**Switching between Directives is a bad practice.**

**The Why:**

Lets assume you have a DropDown Menu ( `<select>` ), and you Have set couple of directives that each one is linked to its option (by `ngModel`).

When the App runs,

You will start with initial directive set by the default value of the `<select>` property, and when you would try to replace that value, you would have to "Delete" the directive from the `DOM` and "Write" use a new one.

By now this should sound to you that it sound like jQuery.

**The What Else should I do:**

Well, you almost answered it for your self: use ng-switch.

[ng-switch by AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

**Notes:**

1) Switching between directive templates is possible (in the exact way you mentioned it, you set couple of templates on the background, and you load the one that fits the most according to the user interaction), but it sounds like you are about to type serious **[Spaghetti Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code)** Which will be very difficult to maintain.

2) Performance: I can't tell if that would affect seriously on the performance of the app, but it will definitely be much harder to maintain.

3) If ng-switch doesn't fit there, You should look at this problem in a different angle.

**EDIT:**

Yes, It's common to do so:
And I've done that in couple of projects.

You have to pass a function to your template property of the new `.directive`.
Example:

```
templateUrl: function (elem, attrs){
  return attrs["template"] == "table" ? "tableTemplate.html" : "listTemplate.html";
}
```

What this means : is that you have to add a so called "Support" attribute to your new directive. In this case I called it template.

It would look like so : `<div new-directive="data" template="table"></div>`

Comment: I'm not talking about switching directives. Let me update the question for better explanation

Comment: You refer to switching templates of the directive right?

Comment: Awesome, seems templateUrl as a function is what I'm looking for.I'll try that. Thanks

Comment: Thumbs up! You can use either use template or templateUrl whatever suits you the most.

Comment: although it seems I can't do that. I need to access scope.template. So let's say tag was `<myDir template="myTemplate" />`, how do I get the real value of `myTemplate` in `templateUrl` function?

Comment: Why can't you achieve that? .. http://plnkr.co/edit/DsoaEWXuL1RluqjcQTYP?p=preview .. Why did you remove the mark? that is the correct answer :S

Comment: because template attribute value in my case not just 'string' it needs to be calculated. See how it's getting set in the scope (check the question)

Comment: I am really surprised that this didn't help you out. P.S you can pass any thing to template | templateUrl function as long as you end up returning a template or URL, so if you need user interaction you could use the attrs['template'] as I suggested, or if it has to be some background calculations it could by any other, even if you need to bring data from the scope

Comment: no, you see I can't just do attrs['template']. What if the value of that attribute needs to be calculated? e.g. `<myDir  template="foo.templUrl" />`. There's no way to access scope in templateUrl function. I'm gonna have to do it in linking function and that prob. will be slow